# Can not print larger size of image using Gimp

Tags: ubuntu-mate, gimp

I scanned an insurance card and want to print it larger than it's actual size so the picture is easier to read.

I tried scanning at a higher dpi.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I think all you have to do is when you choose Print, then click on the Image Settings Tab and then just change the size in inches or pixels to your liking.  You can always use the Print Preview below to show you what it will look like before you print.

Comment: @Terrance It would not let me change the width and height.

Comment: You probably need to rescan the card with a higher DPI allowing you to change the height and width.  If it is too low of DPI it might not resize then.

Comment: A higher DPI did not help. As an temporary alternative, I used tesseract and convert. Image to text. Then copied text into a OfficeWriter doc and increased the font size. :-)

Comment: Not a bad idea to do it as OCR.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a scan done at 600 dpi.

Ofnuts Wrote:

This said, a much simpler approach:

```
 Start a document in your usual word processor (MS Office, Libre Office)
    Import your image into the page
    Resize your image by dragging the image edges
    Print the page
```